# Плавный переход картинок по нажатию на стрелочки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cоздал галерею изображений имеются 14 картинок , по нажатии на стрелки картинки меняются резко , а как сделать *плавный переход*

```js
var thumbnails = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__img'));

function clickOnThumbnail(event) {
    document.querySelector('.image-main').src = this.dataset.fullUrl;
}

for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', clickOnThumbnail);
};

(function arrows(){
    var leftArrow = document.getElementById('arrowleft'),
    rightArrow = document.getElementById('arrowright'),
    initImgNumber = 1;
    maxImgNum = 14;

    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', moveBackvard);
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', moveForvard);

    function moveBackvard(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image-main');
        initImgNumber--;
        if (initImgNumber == 0){initImgNumber = maxImgNum};
        image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };

    function moveForvard(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image-main');
        initImgNumber++;
        if (initImgNumber > maxImgNum){initImgNumber = 1};
        image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };
})();
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <div class="gallery__wrapper">
            <div class="image-main__wrapper">
                <img class="image-main" src="images/fullsize/1.jpg" id="image-main">
                    <div class="arrowleft"><img src="images/left.jpg" id="arrowleft"/></div>
                    <div class="arrowright"><img src="images/right.jpg" id="arrowright"/></div>
                <div class="image-thumbnails__wrapper">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li><img id="thumb-1" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/1.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-2" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/2.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-3" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/3.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-4" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/4.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-5" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/5.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-6" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/6.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-7" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/7.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-8" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/8.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-9" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/9.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-10" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/10.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-11" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/11.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/11.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-12" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/12.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/12.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-13" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/13.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/13.jpg"/></li>
                        <li><img id="thumb-14" class="gallery__img" src="images/thumbs/14.jpg" data-full-url="images/fullsize/14.jpg"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
 .arrowleft {
    position:relative;
    top:205px;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}
.arrowright {
    position:relative;
    left:711px;
    top:205px;
    width:40%;
    float:right;
}
.arrowleft img{
    width:100%;
}
.arrowright img{
    width:100%;
}

.arrowleft img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowleft img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.arrowright img:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:95%;
}
.arrowright img:active{
    width:85%;
}
.gallery__wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
}
.image-main__wrapper{

}
.image-main{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0;
}
.image-thumbnails__wrapper{
   width:785px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:450px;

}
.thumbnails{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnails img{
    border: 2px solid dimgray;
    margin: 0px 1px 17px!important;
}
```

Comment: #box5 {
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color: #ccc;
color: #333;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
height:100px;

text-indent: 0px;
border: 1px solid #888;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;}

#box5:hover {
background-color: #97CE68;
color: #000;
-webkit-transform: translate(0,50px);
-moz-transform: translate(0,50px);
-o-transform: translate(0,50px);
}

Comment: что добавить мне вместо ваших #box ?

Comment: Ivan, id элемента который вы будете перемещать.

Comment: Можете показать наглядный пример , а то что то не понимаю, плзки

Comment: @Pantera id элементов у меня thumbs1 и т.д

Comment: Ivan, https://plnkr.co/edit/bs9NIZbwpWs3lXr1l5yR?p=preview

Comment: @Pantera можете показать на моем бро

Comment: @Pantera  в вашем примере он просто при наведении box спускается вниз на 50 px , а надо чтобы при нажатии на стерлку он плавно переходил вправо или влево картинка менялась